# Unit testing Eclipse's Editor logic in plugins : existing mocks/frameworks?

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I'm working on a plugin which editor augments on the existing JDT (Java) editor
using aspects.

Now, Eclipse text editors that derive from `AbstractTextEditor` are
organized in clear components, following an [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) architecture. Those
components are then accessed through precise paths,
e.g. [reconciliation](http://blog.darevay.com/2007/11/the-eclipse-reconciler/). You can find one example of a custom reconciler and
the assumptions it can (and does) use on the behavior of the editor
[here](http://blog.ankursharma.org/2009/08/adding-spellchecking-to-custom-editors_19.html).

**I'd like to write headless unit tests against those assumptions**, that
would check that my weaving through aspects has not broken anything along
the way. For example, in the case of reconciliation, I would like to
open an editor, input some incorrect content (with respect to some
reconciliation strategy), wait for a while, and check that Problems are
indeed reported.

Note that which problems are reported, or how they would be signaled to
the user in a UI component doesn't concern me : I want 
to test that my swapping a `SourceViewer` for a custom one through aspects 
doesn't break editor logic, *not* my specific reconciliation strategy.

(In fact, I'd
probably mock it for that test. Moreover, the UI testing, being
presumably not runnable in a headless fashion, is beyond the scope of my
question.)

It seems this should be easy to do if the appropriate structures
existed. Do they ? **Is there any test framework or mocks in sync with Eclipse's
architectural assumptions that would let me do what I have in mind** ? Those would have to reproduce workflow behavior of the existing Eclipse editor. Surely this would be among Eclipse's own unit tests, right ? ... though
I can't seem to find anything of the sort. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have asked that [same question](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.platform.core.devel/866) on the eclipse core platform mailing-list, and got a [great answer](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.platform.core.devel/867) from [Dani Megert](http://wiki.eclipse.org/User%3aDaniel_megert.ch.ibm.com) giving me pointers to Eclipse's own test framework. The Junit plugin tests are [released](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.3M5a-201302041400/#JUnitPlugin) for download as part of the extended SDK, and browsing the git source lets you see there are already [tests against the model](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.text.git/tree/) or interacting with some of the `Editor` components.

Comment: By "Eclipse's own test framework" you mean Run as > "JUnit Plug-in Test" ?  The links are dead :/